# In Play Scala, how enumerate a Option[List[String]] of Play's i18n LANG

Tags: scala, playframework

please help. re: ...an Option[List[String]] that contains a list of Play's I18n lang codes, , e.g. ['es', 'en']......

I have no idea how to parse the Option[List[String]]...

Once in the format of a Option[List[String]], how do i write scala code to say, given a language code of 'es', how do I see if the Option[List[String]] contains 'es'?

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the `Option` by using `getOrElse`. Then you can call `contains`on the `List`.

`optListString.getOrElse(List.empty).contains("es")`